# How to show how late a task is in MS-Project 2013?

Tags: tasks, ms-project-2013

When a task is late in the status how can we set it up to show how many days it's late not just late?  I want to see on each task how many days it's late.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to Baseline your plan at the start of the project, when all the planning has been done and you have a plan you are happy with.

Then add the Column 'Finish Variance' to your view.

Whenever the currently forecast Finish date is different to the date it was supposed to have been in the original forecase (i.e. the baselined plan), the difference will be shown in the Finish Variance column.

Comment: this is what i did and still sowing 0 it should show the diff from 4/11 to today

Comment: Late 0% 0 days 4/11/16 4/11/16
Late 0% 0 days 4/11/16 4/11/16
Late 0% 0 days 4/11/16 8/26/16

Comment: You cannot have baselined at the start correctly. Remember, there is no point baselining now that the variance has occurred. It absolutely does work, I double checked everything I said before posting my answer

Comment: meaning to say that there is no way to test it ?

Comment: can u advise any online help or youtube to explore this ?

Comment: Just start up a new Project- Add one task starting today and ending in a few days time. Make sure it's Auto-Scheduled. Baseline it. Add the Finish Variance column. Use 'Start no Earlier Than' to make it start in a few days time instead of today, and observe the value change in the Finish Variance column...

Comment: Thanks allot for your help, i would appreciate if you can be more detailed how to setup the test,  here how i will do it  Task Mode ( set on Auto) second column Task Name from here on please advise in detail how to set the other columns  to get a good result THANKS

Comment: Create a new Project. Create one task in Auto Schedule mode. Baseline that plan. Add the Finish Variance column to your Gantt view. Make the task start at a different time by using the Constraint Type on the Advanced tab => Start No Earlier Than to a different date to the planned start date. You will see the difference between the Baselined end date and the current end date in the Finish Variance column for that task... That is as simple as I can make it. You will need to learn how to use MS-Project by training or research if you don't know what these mean. I cannot help further. Thanks.

Comment: make sure the status date is reflecting the proper date.

Comment: If i do A "Start Date" "Finish Date " and " % work complete" for example if the finish date is 5/3/16 and % work complete is 0 and today is 5/13/16 is there a way to add a column to show that this task is 10 days late ( my question if it can be done by just adding a new column to figure this out ?

Comment: The task is not late, according to MS-Project, if the End Date hasn't moved. What you mean is that you *think* it is late because you have reached the end date and not all of the work has been completed. See my answer to the following question to see how to tell MS-Project to move uncompleted work into the future, which will move the end date and then the task will show as late using the solution above (assuming you DID baseline it) http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/10779/scheduling-tasks-to-start-today/10782#10782